# How to vertically align middle some header text between 2 header images on a website?

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

Here is the url:  www.dealflurry.com
I want to use css.  I cannot figure out how to get the header text that says "Deal Flurry" to be vertically in the middle between the 2 images around it.  The text is staying at the bottom of the images instead of being in the middle.  I have tried putting the text and images in div's but that didn't work the way I did it.  I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `vertical-align: middle;` to both your images in a `class` or an `inline style` (preferably a class) and it will fix it.

Below is your complete updated header div code using inline styles:

```
<div class="header">

<img height="200" src="http://www.dealflurry.com/images/HiRes.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;">

Deal Flurry

<img height="200" src="http://www.dealflurry.com/images/balloons.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!  I was probably overcomplicating the css before.